# Copying Mysql data to a remote server

Tags: mysql

I am running mysql server on my computer.I would like to copy the databases i have created and their tables to a remote server,and that is my website.Is there a software(a windows software) that can help me copy my databases to a remote server?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have external access to both mySQL servers, [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) is a great Windows GUI for mySQL with a good export function.

Alternatively (also needing external access), install the mySQL binaries on your machine and do a simple

```
mysqldump -h hostname_source -u username -p databasename > dump.sql
mysql -h hostname_target -u username -p databasename < dump.sql
```